# Twitter Bootstrap sidebar on the right instead of the left

Tags: html, css, layout, frameworks, twitter-bootstrap

Default configuration for Twitter Bootstrap sidebar is the left hand side. How can I move it on the right ?

UPDATE:
Seems that will be possible with the next release: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/333

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just shift the flow of the sidebar to the right, like so:

```
.container-fluid > .sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
}

.container-fluid > .content {
    margin-right: 240px;
}
```

**EDIT** Demo http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/show/

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you're using something like their fluid layout example shown on github.

```
.sidebar
{
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: ... don't know way but this doesn't work with Bootstrap, I already tryed but cannot overwrite something else setting ...

Comment: default css is here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap.css